# ThreadPoolExecutor is not defined [python3]

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm trying to run the following code, which was directly copied from the documentation:https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures :

```
import executor
import concurrent.futures
import time

def wait_on_b():
    time.sleep(5)
    print(b.result()) # b will never complete because it is waiting on a.                                
    return 5

def wait_on_a():
    time.sleep(5)
    print(a.result()) # a will never complete because it is waiting on b.                                
    return 6


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
a = executor.submit(wait_on_b)
b = executor.submit(wait_on_a)
```

And I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 16, in <module>
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
NameError: name 'ThreadPoolExecutor' is not defined
```

I'm assuming that I forgot to import something, but I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `import concurrent.futures`, or leave the import as-is and use `executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(maxworkers=2)`.

Also note that the example code you copied is designed to deadlock, so it's not going to work properly once you fix the import issue.